# Problem when try to add ++1 for user meta

Tags: query, user-meta

This is my code:

```
$user_user_count = get_user_meta( "_user_count", $user_id );
$user_user_count =  ( isset( $user_user_count ) && is_numeric( $user_user_count ) ) ? $user_user_count : 0;
update_user_meta( $user_id, "_user_count", ++$user_user_count );
```

When I do the action, it adds the meta successfully with 1. The issue when trying to do the action again is that: it's not changed to 2, it's still 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is twofold:

- the `++` operator is applied on an array.
- the user id and the meta key need to be swapped in `get_user_meta()`

So use `get_user_meta( $user_id,   "_user_count", true );` to get user meta.

Note that the third input parameter is *false* by default and an array is returned. Setting it to *true*, returns a single value instead.